# Why $\triangle{ABC}:\triangle{BRC}=AQ:RQ$ where $AQ,RQ$ are not the perpendiculars to the common base $BC$?

Tags: geometry, vectors

In $\triangle ABC$, a point $P$ is taken on $AB$ such that $\frac{AP}{BP}=\frac{1}{3}$ and a point $Q$ is taken on $BC$ such that $\frac{CQ}{BQ}=\frac{3}{1}$. If $R$ is the point of intersection of the lines $AQ$ and $CP$, using the vector method, find the area of $\triangle ABC$ if the area of $\triangle BRC$ is $1$unit.

---

In $\triangle ABC,$let the position vectors of $A,B,C$ are $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$.
By applying the section rule,
Position vector of $P$ is $\frac{3\vec{a}+\vec{b}}{4}$.And the position vector of $Q$ is $\frac{\vec{c}+3\vec{b}}{4}$
Equation of vector $\vec{CP}$ is $\vec{r}=\vec{c}+\lambda(\frac{3}{4}\vec{a}+\frac{\vec{b}}{4}-\vec{c})$
Equation of vector $\vec{AQ}$ is $\vec{r}=\vec{a}+\mu(\frac{\vec{c}+3\vec{b}}{4}-\vec{a})$
Solving the above two equations,
We get the position vector of $R$ is $\frac{\vec{c}}{13}+\frac{\vec{9a}}{13}+\frac{\vec{3b}}{13}$
Now i am stuck here.I referred my book and saw the solution to the problem.Solution was
Since the $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle BRC$ have the same base.Therefore the areas are proportional to $|\vec{AQ}|$ and $|\vec{RQ}|$
I did not understand this concept,since the $AQ$ and $RQ$ are not the perpendiculars to the common base $BC$,how can the areas be proportional to $AQ$ and $RQ$?
Please help me understand this concept.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can the areas be proportional to $AQ$ and $RQ$?

Let $S,T$ be a point on $BC$ such that $AS,RT$ is perpendicular to $BC$ respectively.

Then, since $\triangle{AQS}$ and $\triangle{RQT}$ are similar, we have
$$AQ:RQ=AS:RT.$$
Hence,
$$\triangle{ABC}:\triangle{BRC}=AS:RT=AQ:RQ.$$